# Enable Audit Logs using Cloud Deployment Manager GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-deployment-manager, iaas

I am trying to enable Audit Logs i.e. Data Access Logs using Cloud Deployment Manager in GCP but I am getting some error, below is the script I have created in YAML.

```
resources:
- name: get-iam-policy
  action: gcp-types/cloudresourcemanager-v1:cloudresourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy
  properties:
    resource: <project_id>
  metadata:
    runtimePolicy:
    - 'UPDATE_ALWAYS'
- name: patch-iam-policy
  action: gcp-types/cloudresourcemanager-v1:cloudresourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy
  properties:
    resource: <project_id>
    policy: 
      etag: $(ref.get-iam-policy.etag)
      auditConfigs:
      - auditLogConfigs:
        - logType: ADMIN_READ
        service: allServices
```

Above code is stored in file deploy.yaml and below command is used to create the deployment

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create test --config deploy.yaml
```

I am getting error below

```
(gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-1621334235876-5c2984b310ba1-9e1e602f-d982565d]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
location: /deployments/test/resources/patch-iam-policy
message: '{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudresourcemanager-v1:cloudresourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid
JSON payload received. Unknown name \"auditConfigs\": Cannot find field.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"description":"Invalid
JSON payload received. Unknown name \"auditConfigs\": Cannot find field."}]}],"statusMessage":"Bad
Request","requestPath":"https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/******:setIamPolicy","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

Comment: Please update your question with exact command you're using and the full output you're getting.

Comment: @Wojtek_B I have updated the set of commands used and error

Answer (score 0):

I did some trying on this example and looked up some [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#enable) for this.

Your code seems correct, and all yaml syntax validators say the same.

After I try to deploy your code I get exactly the same error message as you.

This looks like it may be a bug so I would recomment raising an issuge on [Google IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187078&template=1163231).